# How to encrypt a connection string for a wpf application

Tags: wpf, encryption

I have a distributed wpf application that I am trying to find a good way to encrypt the connection string in the app.config. I have tried renaming the app.config to web.config and running the aspnetiis_reg from the command line, that encrypts it but I later found out that only works for the user running the command, I have gotten code online that reads the connection string and encrypts the password and saves the app.config, and when running the application I can run a function that decrypts the password and saves it but that leaves a gaping whole that someone can locate the app.config and see the password when running the application, also you would have to know when the application is closed to go back to encrypt it. Can someone tell me the standard way to encrypt the password and decrypt at runtime with out having to write extra code on a WPF application. To note, I have migrated this application to enterprise library 5.0, the prev version was 1.0 and there was a way of putting the connectionstring in a separate file and encrypting and letting ent library or .net decrypt and not have to worry about it from their. what I was hoping for was a similiar way of just encrypting during build if possible an have .net decrypt without writing extra code for different cases

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to app.config part of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx) msdn document. There is also code samples there.

Comment: I dont think this is going to work because, as the note states in the article "The connection string can only be decrypted on the computer on which it was encrypted." I have a distributed application which means I have to send out the config file unencrypted which is a what I am trying to avoid and then encrypt it when runnning it, if encrypt during build then distribute then nobody else can open it

Comment: if i am wrong about this when do you, call this function toggle?